# Proper way to open a new Dialog from a Dialog

Tags: java, javafx

I some data displayed by a `Dialog`, here is the data class:

```
public class Data
{
    private StringProperty title;
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;

    Data(String title, LocalDate date)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTitle() {return titleProperty.get();}

    public void setTitle(String value) {titleProperty.set(value)}

    public StringProperty titleProperty() {return title}

    public LocalDate getDate() {return dateProperty.get();}

    public void setDate(LocalDate value) {dateProperty.set(value)}

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {return date}
}
```

And here is the `Dialog`:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog<void>
{
    private ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private VBox listDisplay = new VBox();

    CustomDialog()
    {
        this.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);

        if(!list.isEmpty())
        {
            this.getDialogPane.setContent(listDisplay);
            for(Data data : list)
            {    
                VBox listItem = new Vbox();
                listItem.getChildren().add(new Label("Title : " + data.getTitle());
                listItem.getChildren().add(new Label("Date : " + data.getDate());
                listItem.getChildren().add(new Separator());

                listDisplay.getChildren().add(listItem);
            }
        } else {
             this.getDialogPane.setContent(new Label("no data");
        }
    }   
}
```

For testing purpose, I hard coded fake data into the list, but once done, this list will be removed and passed by constructor.

Now, I need to include a button on this Dialog, which when clicked will keep the first Dialog active, open a new Dialog, which will allow the user to input a new data. So this new Dialog will contain a textField, a DatePicker, and a submit button. Once submitted, the new data is added to the list and displayed on the first Dialog.

The problem is I don't know how to create this custom button. Do I need to create a custom `ButtonType` and add it to the Dialog the same way I did it? If so, which is the proper way to create a custom ButtonType?

Or do I need to override one of the `createButtonBar()`, `createButton()` and `createDetailsButton()` of the `DialogPane`?

I'm confused about how JavaFX handles dialogs, and can't figure out which is the proper way to open a new Dialog from an existing Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You’re on the right track.  As the [Dialog documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) and [DialogPane documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html) explain, you do want to create a custom ButtonType, simply by using the ButtonType constructors.

As for opening a new Dialog, the procedure is the same as with any Dialog:  call [initOwner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initOwner(javafx.stage.Window)) with the parent Window.  A Dialog’s window can be obtained from its DialogPane:

```
Dialog<SomeType> secondDialog = new Dialog<>();
secondDialog.initOwner(
    firstDialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow());
```

Comment: I tried that, the problem is that when I create a custom ButtonType, no matter wich ButtonData it is assigned, a click on this new Button will close the first Dialog, and I don't understand why, but a click on the "close cross" doesn't close the Dialog anymore.

Comment: I found a solution with the setOnCloseRequest(EventHandler) method, I consume the event if I don't want the Dialog to be closed. Not 100% sure there isn't a better way to do it. The close 'X' stil doesn't work though.